# f is holomorphic on the unit disk. Show that there exist an sequence ${z_n}$ such that $|z_n|$ converges to 1 and ${f(z_n)}$ is bounded

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove this by contradiction, which comes out that every limit of $|f(z)|$ on boundary tends to infinity. But I have no further idea, any help?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong question. It's "bounded" in the last

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 0):

First, $f$ must have finite number of zeroes. Say $a_k$ of order $\alpha_k$.  Consider $\prod(z-a_k)^{\alpha_k}/f$, which is a holomorphic function on the unit disk and it is $0$ on the boundary. By maximum principle, it is identically $0$, which is of course impossible.

Comment: I'm sorry but f may not be defined on the boundary

Comment: @Meep the fact that $f$ is not defined on the boundary is irrelevant since for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $r=r_{\epsilon}$ st $|g(z)| \le \epsilon, r_\epsilon\le r <1$, where $g$ is the function in the answer above that goes to zero at the boundary (otherwise there would be a sequence $|x_n| \to 1, |g(x_n)| >\epsilon$) so by maximum modulus applied to $g$ on $|z| \le r_{\epsilon}$ we get $|g| < \epsilon$ there; letting $\epsilon \to 0$ proves $g=0$